# Доступ к базе данных PostgreSQL из С++ - приложения

Tags: c++, sql, visual-studio, postgresql, visual-c++

Друзья! Необходимо подготовить курсовой проект по базам данных. Задание состоит в создании базы данных на сервере PostgreSQl и клиентской части, которую планирую реализовать с помощью С++ или С#. Однако не понимаю как организовать связь между клиентской частью и серверной. Буду признателен если подскажите путь к решению данной проблемы.

Comment: libpq (https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/libpq). Так же можете попробовать создать рест-апи с помощью postgrest (http://postgrest.org/en/v5.1/)

Comment: Не могли бы вы подсказать как подключить libpq к моему проекту? Инструкцию я не совсем понял. @goldstar_labs